# Google maps in app webview not showing

Tags: android, webview

I am using WebView to show all the urls I have to. The problem I am facing is that in a particular URL there is a map to be seen and it is seen in external browser. But in the app webview the rest of the website is loaded but the map area is not loaded.

This is my code:

```
webUrlLoad = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_url_load);
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
WebSettings settings = webUrlLoad.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webUrlLoad.loadUrl("http://soie.in/stores");
```

In app webview its like this :

[image]

External Link in chrome :

[image]

Comment: post the url which you passed in webview

Comment: @sasikumar edited the question

Comment: @ParthAnjaria Any *logcat* errors ? Otherwise it should show the output.

Comment: Include something like this in `shouldoverrideurlloading` method: `if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://maps.google.com")) {
                mWebView.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;        
}`

Comment: in the webview the rest of the website is loaded but only the map is not loaded

Comment: @jaydroider getting this log : "Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys", source: https://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/3/intl/en_gb/util.js (210)